# Cannot connect Rapoo S 100 bluetooth headset on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth

I am trying to connect Rapoo s100 bluetooth headset to my Fujitsu laptop.

Initially the headset got discovered in "Add a bluetooth device" window, I connected it, but there was no sound.

Then I connected the device by USB cable, and windows installed the drivers from it. The sound came through the USB cable, but the device disappeared from the devices window.

I restarted the Windows computer, but nothing changed.

It is discovered on the Macbook, on iPhone and on Sony mobile phone, but not on Windows 7. Also, the laptop sees all 3 other devices, and also other bluetooth headsets I have, but not the Rapoo headset.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect and "forget" the bluetooth device. Reinstall the drivers, then reconnect the bluetooth. I had a similar problem with a different bluetooth device and this worked for me.